# how to find distribution between two values

Tags: javascript, function, math, calculation

Let's say I have a page of 210mm x 297mm (A4). It has a print margin of say 5mm each side.
I want to print squares of 1cm x 1cm to fill the page. Each square has a specific margin, say 1mm to the right, 2mm to the bottom.
Now calculating how much squares I can get is easy:

( 210 - 10 ) / ( 10 + 1 ) = 18.181...

( 297 - 10 ) / ( 10 + 2 ) = 23.916...

So 23 rows and 18 columns of squares fit my page.

---

Now I want the first row of squares to be 1cm x 1cm and the last row 5mm x 5mm.

But all the rows in between should be filled up with rows ranging from < 1cm to > 5mm. Decreasing in size from top to bottom.

How would I find the number of rows and each rows square size?

---

The best I can come up with, but needed to try with the step:

```
const heightAvailable = 287;
const maxSizeElement  = 10;
const minSizeElement  = 5;
const marginBottom    = 2;
const step            = 0.15;

function getElementsArray(availableLeft, minElement, maxElement, margin, step) {
  const elementsArray = [];
  elementsArray.push(minElement);
  elementsArray.push(maxElement);

  while(isSizeLeft(availableLeft, minElement, maxElement, margin)) {
    minElement+=step;
    maxElement-=step;
    elementsArray.push(Number((minElement).toFixed(1)));
    elementsArray.push(Number((maxElement).toFixed(1)));

    availableLeft = getSizeLeft(availableLeft, minElement, maxElement, margin);
  }

  return elementsArray.sort(function(a,b) { return b - a;});;
}

function isSizeLeft(total, minElement, maxElement, margin) {
  return 0 < total - (maxElement+margin) - (minElement+margin);
}

function getSizeLeft(total, minElement, maxElement, margin) {
  return total - (maxElement+margin) - (minElement+margin);
}
```

Which returns:

```
array(32) {
  [0]=>
  int(10)
  [1]=>
  float(9.9)
  [2]=>
  float(9.7)
  [3]=>
  float(9.6)
  [4]=>
  float(9.4)
  [5]=>
  float(9.3)
  [6]=>
  float(9.1)
  [7]=>
  float(9)
  [8]=>
  float(8.8)
  [9]=>
  float(8.7)
  [10]=>
  float(8.5)
  [11]=>
  float(8.4)
  [12]=>
  float(8.2)
  [13]=>
  float(8.1)
  [14]=>
  float(7.9)
  [15]=>
  float(7.8)
  [16]=>
  float(7.3)
  [17]=>
  float(7.1)
  [18]=>
  float(7)
  [19]=>
  float(6.8)
  [20]=>
  float(6.7)
  [21]=>
  float(6.5)
  [22]=>
  float(6.4)
  [23]=>
  float(6.2)
  [24]=>
  float(6.1)
  [25]=>
  float(5.9)
  [26]=>
  float(5.8)
  [27]=>
  float(5.6)
  [28]=>
  float(5.5)
  [29]=>
  float(5.3)
  [30]=>
  float(5.2)
  [31]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution doing the calculation with Python and numpy. It should be fairly easy to convert to javascript, though using a bit more code.  The most "complicated" function is `np.linspace` which divides a range in `n` evenly distributed values:

```py
import numpy as np

heightAvailable = 287
maxSizeElement = 10
minSizeElement = 5
marginBottom = 2

for n in range(2, 100):
    sizes = np.linspace(10, 5, n)  # n evenly distributed numbers between 10 and 5 (both included)
    total_space = np.sum(sizes) + (n - 1) * marginBottom
    print(f"With {n} rows; total_space: {total_space:.2f} mm")
    if total_space > heightAvailable:
        sizes = np.linspace(10, 5, n - 1)
        total_space = np.sum(sizes) + (n - 2) * marginBottom
        print(f"Use {n - 1} rows; total_space: {total_space:.1f} mm\nsizes:")
        print(sizes)
        break
```

Output:

```
With 2 rows; total_space: 17.00 mm
With 3 rows; total_space: 26.50 mm
With 4 rows; total_space: 36.00 mm
...
With 28 rows; total_space: 264.00 mm
With 29 rows; total_space: 273.50 mm
With 30 rows; total_space: 283.00 mm
With 31 rows; total_space: 292.50 mm
Use 30 rows; total_space: 283.0 mm
sizes:
[10.          9.82758621  9.65517241  9.48275862  9.31034483  9.13793103
  8.96551724  8.79310345  8.62068966  8.44827586  8.27586207  8.10344828
  7.93103448  7.75862069  7.5862069   7.4137931   7.24137931  7.06896552
  6.89655172  6.72413793  6.55172414  6.37931034  6.20689655  6.03448276
  5.86206897  5.68965517  5.51724138  5.34482759  5.17241379  5.        ]
```

For a more mathematical approach, you can calculate everything symbolically, for example with Python's sympy. Note that the individual size of the little squares is an interpolation between the first and last size.  One can calculate the formula "by hand" using the formula for the triangular numbers and solving a quadratic equation, or let sympy do the work:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Sum, Eq, solve

heightAvailable, maxSizeElement, minSizeElement, marginBottom = symbols(
    'heightAvailable maxSizeElement minSizeElement marginBottom')

i, n = symbols('i n')
total = Sum((i - 1) / (n - 1) * maxSizeElement + (n - 1 - (i - 1)) / (n - 1) * minSizeElement,
            (i, 1, n)) + (n - 1) * marginBottom
sol = solve(Eq(total.simplify(), heightAvailable), n)
print(sol)
print(sol[0].subs({heightAvailable: 287, maxSizeElement: 10, minSizeElement: 5, marginBottom: 2}).evalf())
```

Output:

```
[2*(heightAvailable + marginBottom)/(2*marginBottom + maxSizeElement + minSizeElement)]
30.4210526315789
```

Comment: Yes, I consider checking it. But giving some other people some time for an answer as well.

Comment: Sorry, I think I did that. Maybe I forgot or network issue.